# There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script: ReferenceError: $randomEmail is not defined

Tags: javascript, api, postman, web-api-testing, postman-pre-request-script

I'm trying to send a POST request to create a user using Postman. Require dynamic user email and password for that.

I'm trying assign value in new variable return from Postman inbuilt variable `$randomEmail` in `Pre-request Script` -

```
var new_user_email = $randomEmail;
var new_user_password = $randomPassword;
console.log(new_user_email);
console.log(new_user_password);
pm.globals.set("new_user_email", "new_user_email");
pm.globals.set("new_user_password", "new_user_password");
```

But it throws exception `ReferenceError: $randomEmail is not defined`

while if i use directly in request body like below, it works fine

```
{
  "email": "{{$randomEmail}}",
  "password": "{{$randomPassword}}"
}
```

Any idea about syntax to use it in pre-request script and store for further use ?

Answer (score 1):

in script section you can not directly call $randomEmail , you have to use command **pm.globals.get('varName')**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `{{...}}` syntax within the sandbox environment.

> Since variables in the request builder are accessed using string
>   substitution, they can be used everywhere in the request builder where
>   you can add text. This includes the URL, URL parameters, headers,
>   authorization, request body and header presets.

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments-and-globals/variables/#accessing-variables-in-the-request-builder

You *could* use the `.replaceIn()` function to use string substitution for that syntax.

For example:

```
var new_user_email = pm.variables.replaceIn({{$randomEmail}}")
```

Personally, I would just use the `dynamic variables` directly in the POST body as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variable in the Pre-request Script tab like this:
pm.globals.set("new_user_email", "{{$randomEmail}}");
pm.globals.set("new_user_password", "{{$randomPassword}}");